# Save International Phone DDD on input

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon friends, I thought to put this code to facilitate registration when selecting the DDD of the phone of each country, but it does not save in my database, just the number entered, how do I save the DDD too?

[image]

html:

```
 <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel">


  <script src="flag/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
  <script>
    var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
    window.intlTelInput(input, {
      utilsScript: "flag/build/js/utils.js",
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: You need a way to get the select dropdown's value, and prepend it to your input's value. As the HTML code of the select is not provided, we can't give an exact solution.

Comment: hey thanks for the help but i don't know how to do